# Reset GridView filter

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

What would be the best way to reset filter fields in GridView? It should fill in all inputs with empty values and show all rows.

Answer (score 7):

Built-in `Html` helper provides `resetButton()` method to do that which generates the code like that:

```
<button type="reset"></button>
```

But this will only work inside the form, for example take a look at `_search` view generated in CRUD templates by gii.

For GridView I recommend using another solution: just create link to the same page but without filter parameters.

Example:

```
echo Html::a('Reset', ['index']);
```

**Official documentation:**

- [yii\helpers\Html resetButton()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#resetButton%28%29-detail)
- [yii\helpers\Html a()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#a%28%29-detail)

Comment: if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']){ echo Html::a('Reset', ['index']); } if will check for query string & add reset anchor when user actually filters.